# Fly in a Div into the center of a browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there is any useful tutorials that teaches you via using Jquery to slide in or make a div fly into the users view and then when closed fly back out of view?

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with jquery and CSS DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/KtUEL/90/

CSS

```
#flyin  {width:100px; height:100px; background:#efefef; position:absolute; left:-100px;}
```

jQuery

```
// Calculate current broser width.
var currWidth = $(window).width();
console.log(currWidth);

var startPos = -100;
var endPos = (currWidth / 2) + (startPos / 2);
console.log(endPos);

$('#flyin').animate({left: endPos}, 1000);
```

Comment: Nice one, if it isn't too much to ask, could you explain how it knows how it is in the center?

Comment: Because the end position is "/ 2" exactly half of the window browser (in center)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for it. You can toggle the visibility state by creating a div container. jQuery adds the animation via toggle

http://api.jquery.com/animate/